# Java - Another JFrame On Same Window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

What I want is to make a new JFrame, keeping my current JFrame visible, but not create a new window/program. I can't explain it well, so here is a picture of what I mean:

http://screensnapr.com/e/mkCMlm.png

Sorry if this is confusing in any way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is nothing in the snap except for a part of windows taskbar

Comment: @SunilKumarBM I know, that is what I was showing.

Comment: if you are trying to achieve the grouping, then you can't as it is an OS controlled thing, which groups same windows when the taskbar gets full.

Comment: Agree with AKJ,  if you want to create stacked windows, do it on your own PC.  On my PC, I expect each app. to have a single window unless I explicitly open multiple instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Also you can try to use a dialog rather than frame for the new window.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want JInternalFrame which are a special component in swing that live inside a Container named Desktop. So if you want to have a behaviour like this:

[image]

You definitely need to have inside your JFrame a container named [JDesktopPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html), then you can add JInternalFrame inside this container like this:

```
 MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

For more information you can see [official oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) or [Java2SE code samples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0920__JInternalFrame.htm)